# Is there a way to copy a object file from S3 bucket to EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I cannot make the S3 bucket public. I would like a method to use without AWS command line interface.

Comment: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: Is there any way to copy the file without the CLI? Will SSM documents be helpful here?

Comment: @sye Why do you not want to use the AWS CLI? Are you saying that you want to trigger the copy without logging into the instance? Please Edit your question to tell us more about your situation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a role with S3 access (full or limited, you decide) and attach this role to the EC2 instance. Now you can manipulate files in the S3 from the EC2.